# How do you get jobs & tasks statistics in Azure batch with the Python API?

Tags: python, azure, azure-batch

I started working with Azure batch recently and found I could not get statistics for a given job although fields for that exists.

I am using the Python API, when I poll for job information the `stats` field is always None. The `JobListOptions` class can be used with the `job.list` method but documentation is not very useful.

Going through the [BatchExplorer](https://github.com/Azure/azure-batch-samples/tree/master/CSharp/BatchExplorer) sample code I found out that the `expand` field of the `JobListOptions` class might require to be set to `stats` but I'm still unsure as I'm still not getting stats from the Python API.

Answer (score 3):

You can get stats from jobs as follows:

```
my_batch_client.job.list(
    job_list_options=azure.batch.models.JobListOptions(
        expand='stats'
    )
)
```

Note that it's more efficient to get a job rather than list all of your jobs if you're just interested in a single job. In that case use `my_batch_client.job.get()` with the appropriate `JobGetOptions`.

Or for all tasks under a job:

```
my_batch_client.task.list(
    job_id='MY_JOB_ID',
    task_list_options=azure.batch.models.TaskListOptions(
        expand='stats'
    )
)
```

Similarly, if you are only interested in a single task under a job, query just that task as it's more efficient:

```
my_batch_client.task.get(
    job_id='MY_JOB_ID',
    task_id='MY_TASK_ID',
    task_get_options=azure.batch.models.TaskGetOptions(
        expand='stats'
    )
)
```

Comment: I did actually found the answer on my own, but you did write the answer first!

Comment: It would be a good answer if you could also provide an example to get the status of individual tasks.

Comment: Updated the answer for a single task query.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to get the resource usage statistics for the entire lifetime of jobs & tasks of Azure Batch using Azure Python SDK, so first you need to turn on diagnostics to collect the `ServiceLog` logs as the figure below.

[image]

Then you can get these statistics `stats` from the response of the methods `batch_client.job.get(JOB_ID)` & `batch_client.task.get(JOB_ID, TASK_ID)`.